# UISearchDisplayController doesn't work on iOS 5

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using storyboards, and in a table view controller where I need to search I have added a "Search Bar and Search Display Controller". It works as intended in iOS 6+, with the dimming and searching (and the neat function that hides the navigation bar in the top).

But on iOS5, I'm having mixed results. In one of my table view controllers, the search bar shows up and is clickable, shows the keyboard, but there doesn't seem to be a search display controller connected since nothing happens when you start typing.

In another table view controller, it just crashes before it is pushed on the navigation controller. It's one of those crashes without stack traces that shows some CPU instructions. The viewWillLoad, viewDidLoad, etc functions in my custom table view controller subclass are never even fired, so I'm guessing this too has something to do with the UISearchDisplayController not really liking storyboards in iOS 5. The view is pushed correctly when I remove the search bar from the storyboard.

Anyone has an idea of how to solve this? From what I've read, "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" seems to be working for some people in iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I'll answer this myself.

Seems to be a problem with iOS 5 and search display controller created in Interface Builder. It works like on iOS 6 if you set up the search display controller manually.

Comment: Exactly that it is!! Thanks, you save me from a madness whitout sense! I released my app for ios6 and later I decide make it compatible with ios 5 and this come up! Thanks, I resolved this creating the UISearchController manually in ios5 cases, and assing my IBOutlet for UISearchBar, as you pointed out :D

Answer (score 1):

so I came across your question and this is how I solved my issue.

A little background.  I had a UITableViewController inside my storyboard, with a search display controller, however I was creating the search display controller and searchbar manually.  Instead, dragged in a UISearchDisplayController + UISearchBar into my UITableViewController and hooked them up with IBOutlets.  This fixed my issue, and I hope it will help you and some other people.